# What does this PHP syntax mean

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Can someone tell me what's the `<< 0` for? and other more common alternatives if they exist

```
$newvalue += 1 << 0;
```

Comment: The more common alternative is the comment operator, `// This does nothing`

Comment: an obscure cast to int? (very pointless for an integer constant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<< 0 does nothing. It is probably there to indicate that the value is some sort of flag. If it was something other than 0, than it would shift the value (1) left by x bits, where is is the value replacing 0.

Comment: Can you give an example of what it would do if the value was something other than 0?

Comment: It is a moves the bits in the number over the number of times. 1 << 1 is 2, 1 << 2 is 4, 1 << 3 is 8, etc. Basically, it multiplies by 2 to the power given.

Comment: @JMC `1 << 1` is 2, `1 << 2` is 4, etc. Make yourself familiar with [binary representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) of numbers, then the operator is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 6):

`<<` is the [bitwise left-shift operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).
In this case is seems pretty pointless, since left-shifting 1 by 0 equals 1.